# AngularJS: responsive height in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a div container. Inside that div 4 crads are there. Only on the last card may be two or three cards will come that time the card height should not get impact.

[image]

This is exactly i want. But when I drag and resize the window screen, height should not impact.

- ) All 4 card height should be always same. Either if it is one or two three cards in last card.

[image: image1]

In this three any one will come. and it it dynamically.

[image: image2]

- ) If only one card in the 4th card, height should be 100%. and all card height should be same.
- ) If two cards are ther in 4th card, height should be (100% / 2 ). That time also all cards height should be same. In last card inside that 2 cards height is 50%. and I will add vertical scroll to view that.
- ) If there cards in 4th card, height should be ( 100% /3).

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sandrosc/pen/aprrBG)

```js
 
  $scope.detailsArray[0].details.forEach(function (card) {
        console.log(card);
  });
```

```html
 <div class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 padd-l1" ng-repeat="card in detailsArray[0].details>
            <div class="object-view">
                <div class="get-object">
                   <div class="get-object-wrap">
                     <div id="{{card.value}}"></div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </div>                       
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

```js
{
    "result": [
        {
            Category: ""
            Footer: ""
            L1_Name: ""
            L2_Name: ""
            L3_Name: ""
            Tag: ""
            details: [
                Chart_Caveats: ""
                Chart_Chart_type: ""
                Chart_isFlip: ""
                Chart_order: ""
                count: "1"
            ]
            isactive: "0"
            isfixed: "0"
        },
        {
            Category: ""
            Footer: ""
            L1_Name: ""
            L2_Name: ""
            L3_Name: ""
            Tag: ""
            details: [
                Chart_Caveats: ""
                Chart_Chart_type: ""
                Chart_isFlip: ""
                Chart_order: ""
                count: "2"
            ]
            isactive: "0"
            isfixed: "0"
        },
         {
            Category: ""
            Footer: ""
            L1_Name: ""
            L2_Name: ""
            L3_Name: ""
            Tag: ""
            details: [
                Chart_Caveats: ""
                Chart_Chart_type: ""
                Chart_isFlip: ""
                Chart_order: ""
                count: "3"
            ]
            isactive: "0"
            isfixed: "0"
        },

}
```

Here, count 1, 2 and 3 is there. If count is 1 then height 100%, If count is 2 then height (100% /2)  50%, incase if count is 3 (then 100% / 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need help of JavaScript to achieve this; you could have used flex box, but in all cases it wouldn't occupy the complete area of the div; If the number of divs are too many, you'd probably have to hide the overflow also (which i did);

working **snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sizeDivs();
});

function sizeDivs() {
  var totalDivSize = 0;
  $(".lastDiv").each(function() {
    totalDivSize = $(this).outerHeight();
  })

  var numberOfDivs = 0;
  $(".lastDiv>.internalDiv").each(function() {
    numberOfDivs++;
  })

  var individualHeights = totalDivSize / numberOfDivs;
  individualHeights = individualHeights + "px";
  $(".lastDiv>.internalDiv").css('height', individualHeights);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  sizeDivs();
})
```

```css
.good-review-score {
  background-color: #66CC33;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

.lastDiv {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.lastDiv>.internalDiv {
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
          <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Left 1</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
          <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Left 2</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
          <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 1</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card lastDiv">
        <!-- internal card 1 -->
        <div class='internalDiv'>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
            <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- internal card 2 -->
        <div class='internalDiv'>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
            <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- internal card 3 -->
        <div class='internalDiv'>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
            <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- internal card 4 -->
        <div class='internalDiv'>
          <div class="card-block">
            <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
            <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. This is what exactly I want . Is this possible to do this in angularjs. I want to do this in angularjs.

Comment: Sure, you would use angularJS for ng-repeat only? can you share code that you have tried?

Comment: I have aaded my code . Please look at my post. we are using qlik sense. So entire div object coming from API. So defenitely I have only 4 cards and in the last 4th card only two or three or one card will come.

Comment: can you share the data structure for `$scope.detailsArray`?

Comment: I have updated the $scope.detailsArray format. Could you please have a look and help me how to do like this